# the time of compilation JVM doesn't provide constructor

Tags: java

when we create any constructor (whether as default or argumented) in a class then , JVM why does not povide constructor at the time of compilation?

Comment: your question isn't very clear. can you precise it, if possible with code sample ?

Comment: Harish, I don't understand your question. Can you clarify it ?

Comment: If you create the constructor, why should the JVM do so?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an excerpt from the Java language specification:

> If a class contains no constructor
>   declarations, then a default
>   constructor that takes no parameters
>   is automatically provided:
>
> - If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the
>     default constructor has an empty body.
> - Otherwise, the default constructor takes no parameters and
>     simply invokes the superclass
>     constructor with no arguments.

So in fact the JVM 'provides' the default constructor whenever the class contains no constructor declaration. It is the same as

```
public MyClass() {}
```